# Reducing R figure sizes in lyx?

Tags: r, sweave, floats, lyx

I am using LyX with the Sweave module to generate some R figures within a document. I can't seem to get the figures to be smaller, and they tend to take up half a page which is far too large. 
I have tried:

```
 <<echo=F, fig=T, width=0.5, height=0.5>>=
```

bit it throws an error. Putting any value greater than 1 for width and height make my figure lines thick and font huge but the amount of space it takes up is essentially the same.

So is there anyway to make the output figures smaller?

Comment: see Xu Wang's answer below; Sweave does not support that directly -- people always tell you to use `\setkeys{Gin}` for Sweave, but it is really a bad trick in my eyes so I just added a new option `out.width` in `knitr` (see motivation of `knitr`: https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme and documentation of options http://yihui.name/knitr/options)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11754/how-to-get-correct-dimensions-for-a-ggplot2-plot-in-beamer/11757#11757

Answer (score 6):

Which version of `LyX` are you using? If you are using 2.0.3 (the newest stable version), you can use `knitr` which is more flexible, in my opinion. Note that you have to have `knitr` installed in `R`, which you can do by `install.packages('knitr')`. Then, in LyX, for the module instead of `Sweave` choose `Rnw (knitr)`.

Once you have `knitr` installed in `R` and loaded in `LyX`, this works well for me:

```
<<chunk_name, fig.width=6.5, fig.height=4, background=NA>>=
#plot...
@
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact the most important option to this question is `out.width`, e.g. `out.width='.8\\linewidth'`. BTW, you do not need to quote `NA`, and `echo=FALSE` is irrelevant here. It might also worth mentioning http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/ since there is a screenshot.

Comment: @Yihui thank you for the comments! I should have known that you would see this but I wasn't sure. Really you should give the answer because your answer will be more clear.

Comment: You can edit yours too :)